# Prevent value from going into negative numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I created this code that was supposed to prevent values from going into negative numbers.

```
$makezero = "
SELECT stats.id
     , stats.gold
     , stats.gems
     , users.id
     , stats.attack
     , stats.defense
     , units.worker
     , units.warrior
     , units.archer
     , users.username 
  FROM stats
     , users
     , units 
 WHERE users.username = '$username' 
   AND stats.id = users.id;
";
$zero = mysqli_query($con,$makezero);
$gold = mysqli_fetch_array($zero, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$attack5 = $gold['attack'];
$defense5 = $gold['defense']; 
$worker5 =  $gold['worker'];
$warrior5 =  $gold['warrior'];
$archer5 =  $gold['archer'];
$gems5 = $gold['gems'];

if ($attack5 < 0) $attack5 = 0;
if ($defense5 < 0) $defense5 = 0;
if ($worker5 < 0) $worker5 = 0;
if ($warrior5 < 0) $warrior5 = 0;
if ($archer5 < 0) $archer5 = 0;
if ($gems5 < 0) $gems5 = 0;
```

As you can see, it SHOULD look at the value, see if it is lower than 0 and if so, return it to 0. But it doesn't :( I put it in the header as it's included in every page, so no matter what page, your stats will never go below 0

Simple as that really lol Help?

Comment: Where should it return the values?

Comment: Did you turn on error reporting? (`error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`) If so, what errors are shown?

Comment: Does the units table relate to the others in some way?

Comment: They all relate by the same ID, there's no error report :/

Comment: If so, then you need to specify that somewhere within your query.

Comment: DO you actually update the database with the new zeroed out values?  Seem to me this should be something done before updating this data to database.

Comment: Did you check what exactly does your query return? It is possible that you are getting some strings instead of numbers, and in this case comparison to 0 will not work as intended.

Comment: You do realize your column name would be like `stats.attack` and not `attack`?

Comment: 1) Use *unsigned integers* in MySQL, they cannot be negative. 2) Use `max(attack, 0)`, either in PHP or SQL, as a more elegant way to write that.

Comment: You should print out the `$gold` array. I think the problem is just the associative array part as @MikeBrant pointed out.

Comment: The "pile of unrelated variables" anti-pattern shows itself again. What you should do is create a single associative array that has all of the necessary data in it so you can pass that along easily and have many versions of it at the same time without having M*N variables going on.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE PROBLEM

Where it says

```
$attack5 = 0;
```

That was setting $attack5 to 0, rather than the actual attack in the database

Fixed by changing to

```
$update_unit = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.attack = 0 WHERE stats.id=$id555");
```